# How do I require subdirectories of /app/assets/javascripts in Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, assets, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I want to separate out my javascripts into separate subdirectories in my Rails 3.1 app.

For instance I have a /modules directory inside /app/assets/javascripts

A way to either require all the contents of the directory or each file individually would be helpful.

Edit: To clarify, I want to do this from my application.js coffeescript file.

Comment: Can you post your application.js?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe the way to do this in Sprockets is

```
#= require_tree modules
```

or

```
#= require_tree ./modules
```

if you want to select a subdirectory relative to the CoffeeScript file, rather than relative to `app/assets/javascripts` (see [this issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/525)).